# Разбор записи в файле задач cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Вот строка:

```
# every hour
0 * * * *  /usr/bin/php  -d memory_limit=500M  -f [wwwpath]cron/cron-hour.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Что я уже нашел:

1. `0 * * * *` формат времени из [сайта](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/cron) просто видно что означает.
2. `/usr/bin/php` указывает обработчик
3. `-d` определяет INI php из параметром memory_limit=500M
4. `-f` приступает к обработке файла
5. `[wwwpath]cron/cron-hour.php` место, откуда берётся файл
6. `>` меняем вывод результата

и далее — темнота. Пожалуйста, растолкуйте с 6-го пункта включительно, как дальше работает интерпретатор?

Comment: Это перенаправление ошибок в первый поток (т.е. в `/dev/null`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Что за магическое `something > /dev/null 2>&1`?

Как вы уже правильно заметили, `>` перенаправляет поток. Цитируя статью [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html):

```
COMMAND_OUTPUT >
   # Redirect stdout to a file.
   # Creates the file if not present, otherwise overwrites it.

   # Перенаправляет stdout в файл
   # Создает файл, если он не существует, в противном случае, перезаписывает
```

Обратите внимание, `>` перенаправляет только `stdout`, но помимо него есть еще два потока: `stdin` и `stderr`. Последний нас интересует больше всего.

У каждого потока есть свой дескриптор:

- `stdin`: 0
- `stdout`: 1
- `stderr`: 2

Соответственно, нам осталось перенаправить куда-нибудь в укромное место поток `stderr`. Это можно сделать с помощью команды `2>`. В данном случае, мы перенаправляем его в поток `stdout`, что эквивалентно `2>&1`:

```
M>&N
   # "M" is a file descriptor, which defaults to 1, if not set.
   # "N" is another file descriptor.

   # "M" - дескриптор файла. По умолчанию - 1
   # "N" - дескриптор файла, в который будет организовано перенаправление.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=500M -f [wwwpath]cron/cron-hour.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Это одна-единственная команда баша.

- `> /dev/null` означает, что вывод будет записываться в файл `/dev/null` (специальный файл, который всегда пуст) - то есть дескриптор STDOUT (или просто 1) будет открытым файлом `/dev/null`
- `2>&1` означает, что STDERR (2) будет просто дубликатом STDOUT (1)

Короче говоря, и обычный вывод, и вывод ошибок не будет нигде отображаться и не будет никуда записываться.